# axior request with an image ?

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

1- react native application 
2- handling the request with axios 
3- backend server with Laravel 5.4

- uploadImage function in the react native app
  [image]
- console log 
  [image]
- backend function to store the image in server + updating the Model
  [image]

what i have made wrong ? !! thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I GOT IT , THANKS , MAKE A REF FOR ANYONE MAY FACE SUCH STUPID CONFLICT.